# Adding an abbreviation for spaces in vim

Tags: linux, vim, whitespace

I am trying to add the following abbreviation in vim, but its not working.

```
    noreabbrev <space><space>  .<space>
```

Its just like in most modern phones keypad.

so can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here and how to make it work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of abbreviations: full-id, end-id, non-id, each with particular conditions on the sets of allowed characters. See `:help abbreviations`. Two spaces aren't allowed in any of them.

You have to use an `:inoremap` (and live with the inevitable delay with which the first space character will appear in the buffer), or build a complex `:inoremap <expr> <Space>` that checks the previous character and only then does its magic.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly hacked this together.  Put it in a file called `InsertSpace.vim` or whatever and either source it from your vimrc, or place it in `~/.vim/plugin/` (`~\vimfiles\plugin` on Windows):

```
function! s:InsertSpace()
    if getline('.')[col('.')-3:col('.')-2] =~ '[^. ]\s$'
        return "\<bs>. "
    else
        return ' '
    endif
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <space> <SID>InsertSpace()
```

This isn't going to be perfect, but it can be refined.